# How can I differentiate if a picture is made fron the internal or external camera

Tags: android, android-image, android-photos, android-image-capture

Hello I am trying to make an app and I need to differentiatie if a photo has been tanken forn the internal or external camera of my smartphone. I need this because my smartphone rotates the photos in one or another direction depending on which camera the photo has been made for.

I need to know to be able to apply the rotation in the correct direction to leave the picture ok.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by internal camera and external camera. please expalin

Comment: Thank you for your interest I already managed to solve it a greeting.